# Error with Firebase: The file 'obj\iPhone\Debug\Frameworks\FirebaseFirestore.framework\FirebaseFirestore' already exists. VS 22

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an application for my company using C# and Xamarin.
I'm trying to testing my App to different devices but I have a problem:
My application works on my real Android phone, on Virtual Android, on Virtual Iphone but
It does not work on my real Iphone.

When I try, I get this error:

```
The "UnpackFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The file 'obj\iPhone\Debug\Frameworks\FirebaseFirestore.framework\FirebaseFirestore' already exists.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.CopyTo(String destFileName)
   at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows.Zip.CopyDirectory(String source, String destination) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Zip.cs:line 31
   at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows.Zip.Extract(String sourceFileName, String destinationPath) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Zip.cs:line 17
   at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Tasks.UnpackFrameworks.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Tasks/UnpackHotRestartFrameworks.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I'm using visual studio 2022 with C# and Xamarin.

I tried to delete obi and bin folders much times but nothing.
I also tried to apply this modify to Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets file but when I try to use Firebase I get this error

```
Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[635:177579] System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Plugin.CloudFirestore.FirestoreProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: firestore
  at Plugin.CloudFirestore.FirestoreWrapper..ctor (Firebase.CloudFirestore.Firestore firestore) <0x104558138 + 0x0001a> in <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>:0 
  at Plugin.CloudFirestore.FirestoreProvider..cctor () <0x1039aa4c0 + 0x00014> in <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestoreImplementation.get_Instance () <0x1039a99b0 + 0x00000> in <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>:0
```

If I test an application without Firebase component, It works correctly.

Can someone help me?

Comment: From your error, I found an issue on Github [Using VS22 Xamarin #437](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/437),which might be useful for you.